# optimizing a WooCommerce site, in production

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What can WooCommerce site owners do to optimize their site. Those owners are those to whom I developed an online store.

After some time of operation, the site gets bigger in disk size, I suppose it's due to a growth in the mySql database.

Is there a plugin that the customers can use to optimize their site without knowing anything about databases and wordpress tech stuff?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of guides on how to optimize WordPress websites. [Here is one](https://wp-power.org/wordpress-performance/ultimate-guide-wordpress-performance/). The most basic thing everyone should do is to use a caching and image optimization plugin.

But for WooCommerce specific actions that you can take, the one thing you can do is install the [custom orders table](https://github.com/liquidweb/woocommerce-custom-orders-table) plugin. This puts all of the WooCommerce data in a separate database table. However, it does require using wp-cli, so a person would have to know how to SSH in and run the command. It is easy to automate doing this though.

As for bigger disk sizes, if a WordPress database is more than a few GB in size something is terribly wrong. Normally it's only a few hundred MBs. So no, large websites don't happen because the database growing. It's from the stuff getting stored in the wp-contents folder. WordPress stores will store multiple copies of each image at different resolutions, and this along with having lots of plugins and themes downloaded can increase the size of the website, but it still won't get ridiculously big. Although once you add a backup plugin on top of the size of the website gets multiplied. A good backup plugin should default to not keeping around too many local backups. The most serious issues I've seen happen when there are multiple backup plugins, and they start including in their backups all of the backups created by the other plugin. You will then get exponentially bigger backups, and the size of the website will quickly get out of control.

So that's what causes websites to be bigger, and website owners will inevitably add more plugins and images to the site over time, increasing the size of the website, but even worse, all of the additional plugins will slow the website down.

You also need to make sure you're clients are using a good webhost. The guide I shared has some criteria you can use to judge a good hosting company. The one thing that many hosting companies don't have is some sort of in memory cache. Look for hosting companies that use Varnish or Litespeed or Nginx's proxy_cache to cache pages before they hit WordPress.

Comment: Thank you for answering

Comment: I built a demonstration online store, and I noticed that, by creating orders, modifying products, etc. (no backups), that database was getting larger, but with a few modifications, I am talking of less than 10 products. By using the site, the site went from 300 Mb to 900 Mb, I don´t know why this happens, and everything was working fine, didn´t have any issues. What could be happening?

Comment: The most products that any of the websites I manage has is 321 products. The website has been in operation for over 5 years. The total size of the database is only 437 Mb. If you're that worried about the size of the database, I can host the website for you. I don't put any limits on the size of databases I host, and if the size gets too large, I would go in and fix whatever malconfigured plugin is causing problems.

Comment: Using phpMyAdmin or whatever program your webhost provides you to manage the DB you should be able to see a breakdown of which tables are using the most data, and then you could drill down further to figure out what plugins/theme are using up the most space.

Comment: Thanks. For the moment it's not necessary, but I 'll remember it for future needs.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but you can also setup this plugin to clean out stale data in the database once a week -- https://wordpress.org/plugins/rvg-optimize-database/. That'll clear out old page revisions, sometimes plugins will cache stuff in the database or store temporary information about a visitor that will need to be periodically cleared, WooCommerce stores old cart sessions in the database. Stuff like that.